# Getting "Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 1: did not find expected key" in helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

My help `values.yaml` file looks like this (don't worry about the user password, this is an example)

```
configMap:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-config
  values:
    mongoUrl: mongo-service
secret:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-secret
  values:
    mongoUser: bW9uZ291c2Vy
    mongoPassword: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==
```

When I run `helm install  --dry-run mongo ./mychart` I'm getting `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: cannot load values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 1: did not find expected key`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `.Release.Name` is not allowed inside Helm's `values.yaml` file if I understood it correct.
Changing to the following fixed it

```
  name: mongo-config
  values:
    mongoUrl: mongo-service
secret:
  name: mongo-secret
  values:
    mongoUser: bW9uZ291c2Vy
    mongoPassword: bW9uZ29wYXNzd29yZA==
```

Comment: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3558

Comment: The names of these objects should probably be specified in your `templates/*.yaml` files; you probably don't need the administrator to manually specify them.